# Equicontinuous homeomorphism and compact metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, dynamical-systems, compactness, equicontinuity

Let $(X, d) $ be a metric space and $f: X \rightarrow X$ be a homeomorphism on $X$.

1) We say that $f$ is semi-equicontinuous if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $d(x, y) < \delta $ implies $d(f^{n} (x), f^{n} (y)) < \epsilon $ for all $x, y\in X$ and all $n \geq 0$. (This is also a definition of equicontinuity of continuous maps).

2) We say that $f$ is equicontinuous if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $d(x, y) < \delta $ implies $d(f^{n} (x), f^{n} (y)) < \epsilon $ for all $x, y\in X$ and all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

3)  We say that $f$ is an isometry if $d(f(x), f(y)) = d(x, y)$ for all $x, y\in X$.

4) If $X= \mathbb{R} $ and $0 < \alpha < 1$, then $f(x) = \alpha x$ is non-isometry semi equicontinuous homeomorphism but not equicontinuous.

Questions :

1) Can we find a non-isometry semi-equicontinuous but not equicontinuous homeomorphism on a compact metric space. A class of such maps on distinct compact metric spaces are needed, if exists.

2) If $f$ is an equicontinuous homeomorphism on a compact metric then $f$ must be an isometry?

Comment: For 2): Being isometry depends on the metric, which can be easily changed. Take for example, $X=[0,1]$, $f(x)=1-x$ and $d(x,y)=\lvert\arctan{x}-\arctan{y}\rvert$.

Comment: 2) Not necessarily. For instance, let $f$ be any bijection of a finite metric space.

Comment: Perhaps the OP meant: If $f$ is an equicontinuous homeomorphism on a compact **metrizable** space $X$ then **there exists a metric $d$ on $X$** such that $f$ is an isometry with respect to $d$?

Comment: Alex Ravsky: finite metric space is discrete. Hence every homeomorphism or a bijective map must be an isometry.

Comment: user539887: Space is already compact metric. No need to choose metrizable thing. In questions (1) and (2) I am assuming same compact metric for equicontinuity and isometry. The $arctan$ metric you are choosing is not compact.

Comment: No. A finite metric space $(X,d)$ is discrete and there is $\delta>0$ such that $d(x,y)<\delta$ implies $x=y$ for all $x=y$. This implies that each bijection $f$ of  $X$ is equicontinuous. But $f$ is not necessarily an isometry. Moreover, each bijection of $X$ is an isometry iff there exists a constant $c>0$ such that $d(x,y)=c$ for each $x\ne y\in X$.

Comment: PS. You can use @Name (for instance, @AlexRavsky) in your comments for an automatic notification of the mentioned person about the comment.

Comment: You are welcome. I’m trying to answer your first question, but it looks much more harder than the second.

Comment: Oh, thanks @AlexRavsky for the tip to refer names.. Isometry means distance preserving map. So, if $f$ is bijective on discrete space then $d(f(x'), f(y')) = d(x, y) =0$ or $1$, depending $x = y$ or $x\neq y$.

Comment: A discrete topology on a finite set $X$ (of size at least $2$) can be determined not only by the metric $d$ which you present, but also by many other metrics. For instance, let $X=\{1,2,3\}$ and $d(x,x)=0$ for each $x\in X$, $d(1,2)=d(2,3)=1$, and $d(1,3)=2$.

Comment: @AbdulGaffarKhan You wrote in your answer to my comment; "The *arctan* metric you are choosing is not compact." Could you, please, explain what you mean by that?

Comment: Oh yeah this way we can do that. Thanks @AlexRavsky. But it will be much more interesting if you can provide me some idea to construct such examples on non discretel spaces like on an unit circle, torus, biinfinite product of two symbols?

Comment: @user539887 misunderstood from my side.. I read it as $R$..

Comment: @user539887  any way to answer, question (1). Thanks

Comment: @AlexRavsky any way to answer, question (1). Thanks

Comment: I'm stuck, but I still have a hope. Also I found a general point of view at question (1), which I'm going to write later.

Answer (score 1):

2) A family $\mathcal F$ of functions between metric spaces $(X,d)$ and $(X’,d’)$ is *uniformly equicontinuous*, if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $d(x,y)<\delta$ implies $d’(f(x),f(y))<\epsilon$ for all $x,y\in X$ and all $g\in \mathcal F$. So a homeomorphism $f$ of a space $(X,d)$ is semi-equicontinuous iff a family $\hat f^+=\{f^n:n\ge 0\}$ is uniformly equicontinuous and is equicontinuous iff a family $\hat f=\{f^n:n\in\Bbb Z\}$ is uniformly equicontinuous.

Uniform equicontinuity can be naturally defined for [uniform spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space). Namely, a family $\mathcal F$ of functions between uniform spaces $(X,\mathcal U)$ and $(X’,\mathcal U’)$ is *uniformly equicontinuous*, if for every $U’\in\mathcal U’$ there exists $U\in\mathcal U$ such that $(f\times f)(U)\subset U’$ for all $g\in\mathcal F$.

It is easy to check that a family $\mathcal F$ of functions between metric spaces $(X,d)$ and $(X’,d’)$ is uniformly equicontinuous iff $\mathcal F$ is uniformly equicontinuous with respect to uniform spaces $(X,\mathcal U_d)$ and $(X’,\mathcal U_{d’})$, where $\mathcal U_d$ and $\mathcal U_{d’}$ are the uniformities induced by metrics $d$ and $d’$, respectively. That is a base of $\mathcal U_d$ is $\{U_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$, where $U_n=\{(x,y)\in X\times X: d(x,y)<1/n\}$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$, and, similarly, a base of $\mathcal U_{d}$ is $\{U’_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$, where $U’_n=\{(x,y)\in X’\times X’: d’(x,y)<1/n\}$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$.

It is easy to check that a topology induced by the uniformity $\mathcal U_d$ on the set $X$ is the same as a topology $\tau_d$, induced by the metric $d$ on $X$.

At last we came to a key point of this answer. If $X$ is a compact space then there exists a unique uniformity $\mathcal U$ on $X$, inducing the topology of space $X$, see, for instance, Theorem 8.3.13 from “General topology” by Engelking below. On the other hand, there can be many metrics on $X$ inducing its topology. We can construct them as follows. Let $(X,d)$ be any metric space and $h:X\to X$ be any continuous function. For each $x,y\in X$ put $d’(x,y)=d(x,y)+|h(x)-h(y)|$. It is easy to see that a function $d’$ is a metric on $X$. Since $d’(x,y)\ge d(x,y) $ for each $x,y\in X$, a topology $\tau_{d’}$ induced on $X$ by $d’$ is stronger than a topology $\tau_d$ induced on $X$ by $d$. On the other hand, let $x\in X$ be any point and $\epsilon>0$ be any real number. Since the function $h$ is continuous at $x$, there exist $0<\delta\epsilon/2$  such that $|h(x)-h(y)|<\epsilon/2$ for each $y\in X$ such that $d(x,y)<\delta$. Then $d’(x,y)<\epsilon$. Thus $\tau_{d’}$ is weaker than $\tau_d$, so $\tau_{d’}=\tau_d$.

We can conclude that if $X$ is a compact metrizable space and $f$ is a homeomorphism of $X$ then whether $X$ is equicontionuous does not depend on a metric inducing the topology of the space $X$, but 
whether $X$ is an isometry depends on this metric and holds only in special cases.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]